# Pentaho input depending upon date

Tags: pentaho

I want to use input file out of available file which is modified on current date and skip other.

I have created transformation as get file name->microsoft excel output(to get lastmodified date)->modified java script.  In javascript i want to check lastmodified date with current date. File with matched criteria will be given to Text file ouput.  I am new to pentaho, still exploring pentaho.

please help me regarding this requirement transformation

Comment: Use the "Filter Rows" step :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand your question, you need to filter the input and take some action based on theses input values. Use the "Filter Rows Step", after your input, the set the necessary conditions to be matched and finally, in the Filter Rows Step, you have option for multiple outputs, depending on the conditions you defined. Just, drag & drop the target step for True or False cases. Bingo!

Comment: Okay .. to compare with current date what i need to enter in value field in filter rows dialog box